# Download from Glacier

Tags: boto, amazon-glacier

I am able to upload a file to glacier vault. But how do I download a file?

```
import boto
ACCESS_KEY_ID = "abc"
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "pqr" 
glacier_connection = boto.connect_glacier(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

vault = glacier_connection.create_vault("backup")
archive_id=vault.upload_archive("aws.sh")
```

I expected the following code would download a file from glacier. But it does not work.

```
retrieve_job=vault.retrieve_archive(archive_id)
if retrieve_job.completed:
    retrieve_job.download_to_file("test.pl")
```

Comment: Could you expand on the "but it does not work" thing?  Do you get stack trace? What actually happens?

Comment: Do you still need a hand with this?

Comment: Retrieving a file takes 4 hours. Should you use a While loop instead?